# SSRS Date Parameters not displaying correct dates

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with a couple date parameters called fromDate and toDate.  The report tablix property is set to filter fromDate >= date and toDate <= date.  However, when I run the report let's say with the fromDate 19-12-2020 and the same date in toDate 19-12-2020 it won't display anything.  To get the 19th I'd have to select a day over like 20-12-2020 and this won't display data for the 20th as well.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  How can I fix this bug?  Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: is your date field a "datetime" type with time component recorded in the same field? e.g. "2020-12-21 09:40:46.800" .  It appears to be so from your question. You need to convert your date to a date type . something like convert(date,date) between fromDate and toDate

Comment: Hi Harry, my date field is converted to Date but my parameters are set to Date/Time so that I can use the calendar.

Comment: can you show some examples of your data and change the query to use between from and to date?

Comment: Hi @Harry, I tried to use the parameters in the query but got the same results.

Comment: Hi @Harry, when I execute the query in the sql server I get dates like this: 2018-01-31 19:16:07.000.  The date field in the body of the report I configured under its properties Number - Date - 1/31/2000.  The parameters are set as Date/Time under Data Type.  For some reason the range of the parameters is off by one day.

Comment: exactly as I suspected.. your where clause should be along the lines of where convert(date,yourcolumnname) between yourstartparameter and your endparameter

Comment: You are a genius @Harris.  That worked.  Thanks a million.  You are the best.

Comment: great.. please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Date column from your source table is date time like -

> 2018-01-31 19:16:07.000

and your parameters that are date time will be sending this -

> 2018-01-31 00:00:00.000

.. no records will be returned.. Unless you have exactly 00:00:00.000 as your minutes and hours.

You need to convert your column to date in your where clause like this:

```
where convert(date,yourtable.yourcolumn) between @start_date and @end_date
```